# Django how to display saved media file name on custom input file?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-media

I have made a form where user inputs personal information including a file.

I want that whenever user opens his profile then he/she must be able to see already attached file name in custom input field or at least if he/she doesn't choose any new picture, input file field value must be set to previously attached picture url.

This is what I tried

```
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            {% if details.picture.url != '' %}
            <label for="front">Picture <span class="text-muted">
                <a href='{{details.picture.url}}'>{{details.picture}}</a></span></label>

            {% else %}
            <label for="front">ID Card (front) <span class="text-muted">Take a snap and upload</span></label>

            {% endif %}

            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="front" name="front" value="{{details.picture.url}}" >
  </div>
```

but the input field is always empty.

Kindly suggest some way around of it.

Comment: Please elaborate `but didn't work` - error, wrong value, no value or what?

Comment: @IvanStarostin See edit

Comment: Please show corresponding `view` code. And tell what happens if you put `{{details.picture.url}}` outside of `<input>` tag - does the url exist in rendered page?

Comment: Well, I would suggest to set the field value in views.py. Whenever you initialize form check if the user have image or not and then set the file value internally. follow [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/initial-form-data-django-forms/)

Comment: @IvanStarostin yes url exsists

Comment: Please show the view/form python code.